# Async calls are not called

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I have a very weird bug on my code but really unable to understand what's wrong. I am trying to implement a very simple client that is sending a file to a server via socket;

The file is sent in this way:

1. Connect to server
2. Send an header with info about the file (filename and size for now)
3. While chunks are available

   1. Read chunk of bytes from the file
   2. Send a header of the chunk.
   3. Send the data of the chunk

In Boost.Asio it becomes:

```
  async_connect( // 1.
    async_write(   // 2.
      while (file)  // 3.
        async_write(  // 3.2
          async_write(  // 3.3
        )
    )
  )
```

The problem is that I never reach the 3.2 (the functions that should send the chunk header). It seems like the program got stuck. I also try to put a throw inside to see if it crash.

Below a short snippet:

```
namespace net = boost::asio;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using net::ip::tcp;

class Client {
 public:
  Client(net::io_context &io_context, const tcp::resolver::results_type &endpoints) {
    net::async_connect(socket_, endpoints, [this](const auto &, auto) { sendMessageHeader(); });
  }

 private:
  void sendHeader() {
    // Prepare message
    // ...
    net::async_write(socket_, net::buffer(header_.data(), header_length()),
                     [this](const auto &, auto) { sendChunks(); });
  }

  void sendChunks() {
    // ...
    while(file) {
      // prepare the chunk header
      // ...
      chunkHeaderQueue_.push();
      chunkBufferQueue_.push();

      // send the header
      net::async_write(socket_, net::buffer(chunkHeaderQueue_.front().data(), chunkHeaderQueue_.front().size),
                       [this](const auto&, auto) {

                         auto &chunk = chunkBufferQueue_.front();
                         chunkHeaderQueue_.pop();
                         net::async_write(socket_, net::buffer(chunk), [this](const auto&, auto) {
                           chunkBufferQueue_.pop();
                         });
                       });
    }
  }

 private:
  boost::asio::io_context &io_context_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
  MessageHeader header_;
  ChunkHeaderQueue chunkHeaderQueue_;
  ChunkBufferQueue chunkBufferQueue_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // used for async operations
    net::io_context io_context;

    // resolver will connect to the server
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
    auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]);

    // create the client and start all async operations
    Client client(io_context, endpoints, {argv[3]});

    // it will block until all async operation will be done!
    io_context.run();

  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    fmt::print("Exception: {}\n", e.what());
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you store chunk as reference, `auto &chunk` ? You take reference to `front`, and then call `pop`? It is undefined behaviour. By popping you remove object, what makes dangling pointer. You use *for* loop with `async_XXX`, it is rather bad idea. You should wait until proper handler will be called, then next `async_XXX` invocation would be invoked. If you want to use *for* loop, call synchronous functions of asio.

Comment: The program hangs because the socket i/o is deadlocked: before you complete the first write you try to start another write on the socket.  This will not work.  Async in this case means async with regard to the rest of the program not the writes to the socket.  Restructure the program so that you put all the headers and blocks on a single queue and then in another thread pull blocks off the queue and push them through the socket synchronously.

Comment: So if I have I call `async_write` multiple time before it finish is a dead lock on the socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sendChuncks` you are issuing multiple writes on the socket without waiting for completion . Also you pop twice from `chunkBufferQueue_`

Async operations shouldn't be used like this, They should be chained and your function should look like this :

```
void sendChunk()
{
    auto& chunk = chunkBufferQueue_.front();
    net::async_write(socket_, net::buffer(chunck), 
    [this](const auto&, auto) {
        chunkBufferQueue_.pop();
        sendHeader();
    });
}

void sendHeader()
{
    if(!file)
        return;
    chunkHeaderQueue_.push();
    chunkBufferQueue_.push();

    auto& header = chunkHeaderQueue_.front();
    net::async_write(socket_, net::buffer(chunck), 
    [this](const auto&, auto) {
        chunkHeaderQueue_.pop();
        sendChunk();
    });
}
```